# How to get a list scaled down pods in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift

Besides making a list of pods and list of deployments and then comparing, is there a way in the cli
and/or OCP console to list the scaled down pods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the `oc get hpa` command provides a table showing min/max and current replicas.

```
oc get hpa hpa-resource-metrics-memory

NAME                          REFERENCE                       TARGETS         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
hpa-resource-metrics-memory   ReplicationController/example   2441216/500Mi   1         10        1          20m
```

Running a `describe` on specific HPAs or `oc get event` allows you to see the downscaling events.

```
oc describe hpa hpa-resource-metrics-memory

Name:                        hpa-resource-metrics-memory
Namespace:                   default
Labels:                      <none>
Annotations:                 <none>
CreationTimestamp:           Wed, 04 Mar 2020 16:31:37 +0530
Reference:                   ReplicationController/example
Metrics:                     ( current / target )
  resource memory on pods:   2441216 / 500Mi
Min replicas:                1
Max replicas:                10
ReplicationController pods:  1 current / 1 desired
Conditions:
  Type            Status  Reason              Message
  ----            ------  ------              -------
  AbleToScale     True    ReadyForNewScale    recommended size matches current size
  ScalingActive   True    ValidMetricFound    the HPA was able to successfully calculate a replica count from memory resource
  ScalingLimited  False   DesiredWithinRange  the desired count is within the acceptable range
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                 From                       Message
  ----     ------                   ----                ----                       -------
  Normal   SuccessfulRescale        6m34s               horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 1; reason: All metrics below target
```